# Convenient constructor ARC objective c

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am very new for objective c.
I have experiment a convenient constructor for memory leaks.

Here is my constructor

```
+(Myobject * ) test{
    return [[self alloc] init];
}
```

and I test it with this code in main.m

```
Myobject * __weak g = [Myobject test];
NSLog(@"%@",g);
```

I wish the log will say (null) because pointer in constructor is died when it out of scope and arc will do remove this object out of memory since there is no strong pointer to retain it.
just only weak pointer.

But in the log it say something that an object is still alive.
In my understand now there is a strong pointer that retain this object in the constructor method.So it will be there forever.

So how can i get rid of that pointer?
Or Did i miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `test` method returns an *autoreleased* object. If there is no strong reference to the object, it will be destroyed at the end of the current autorelease pool. You can verify that with

```
Myobject * __weak g;
@autoreleasepool {
    g = [Myobject test];
    NSLog(@"%@", g); // object still exists here (Correction: might still exist here, see Nikolaus Ruhe's comment)
}
NSLog(@"%@", g);  // should output "(null)"
```

Due to ARC naming conventions the behaviour is different if you rename your method to `newTest`. In that case it returnes a retained object which is released immediately.

The exact semantics can be found in [Automatic Reference Counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), in the sections "3.2.2. Retained return values" and "3.2.3. Unretained return values".

**Correction:** As Nikolai Ruhe correctly pointed out, it is not *guaranteed* that the object returned by `[Myobject test]` is in the autorelease pool, the compiler can remove retain/release/autorelease calls during optimization.

Comment: +1 good explanation. Minor correction: ARC does not guarantee that the object goes to the autorelease pool. If the calling and the called method are compiled with ARC the autorelease might be removed during optimization.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe: Thanks. You are right, I have added this information to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes the log is correct. As I can see even though g is a weak reference but it is still pointing to a allocated class object. Moreover, g is still not out of scope here, so there is no question of ARC deallocating it.

Comment: -1 The idea of weak references is that the object can be released while the pointer still exists.

Comment: @Nikolai Ruhe Thanks for updating me, but can you please explain more on how this object g got deallocated outside autoreleasepool

Comment: Well, for one: it hasn't. But ARC *could* deallocate the object immediately since there are no strong references to it after `test` returns.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe How Myobject __weak *object = [[Myobject alloc] init]; gives a warning but above code does not

Comment: @EvolGate: Because methods starting with "alloc", "copy", "new" or "init" have different semantics. As I said in my answer, if `test` is renamed to `newTest` then it is released immediately.